# Setup Azure API management as proxy to forward and cache API calls

Tags: azure, caching, azure-api-management

In the project I'm working on, we have a system where we have a back-end application which will handle the authentication/authorization, and through this the front-end clients will send requests and receive responses to/from other services.

Now we are also contemplating adding Azure API management to the mix, placing it in-between the back-end and other services, as a passthrough, solely because we want to take advantage of the API caching feature.

Does this sound like a good idea? Is this actually an use-case for Azure API management or should I reconsider my project's architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are looking for is an intermediary cache for a single region, you might find API Management overkill for your needs.  Although, it would be an easy way to get started.

Consider if you might want add in rate limiting, request/response logging and analytics in the future. Or if you might want an intermediary to handle routing for versioning.  Or if you need to do geo-distributed caching.  If some of those features may be useful in the future, then putting Azure API Management in might be a quick way to get started and prepare you for the future.

Comment: Thank you for your response. For now, we are only really concerned about caching REST API responses so APIM may be an overkill. Is there an alternative you can suggest for my project?

Comment: Squid https://varnish-cache.org/intro/index.html#intro and Varnish https://varnish-cache.org/intro/index.html#intro are HTTP intermediary caches